# R adding a variable within a hyperlink

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to create a code that will allow me to update hyperlinks based on a variable or, eventually, by looping through a character vector.

What I'd like to do is be able to set the hyperlink up so that if I were looking for a job on Careerbuilder I could precede the rvest code with

```
job <- "Data Science"
```

and then have

```
jobsearch <- read_html("https://www.careerbuilder.com/jobs-data-science?
keywords=Data+Science&location=")
```

If I then wanted to look at Bartending jobs I would just have to update the job variable

```
job <- Bartender
```

and then have

```
jobsearch <- read_html("https://www.careerbuilder.com/jobs-data-science?
keywords=Bartender&location=")
```

Eventually I'd like to be able to have this just run down a list of jobs but I'm hoping to walk before I crawl.

Comment: Maybe using the `paste` function: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.1/topics/paste

Comment: Scraping careerbuilder (which you are obviously doing) is a violation of their terms of service (they also have a robust robots.txt for a technical control as well). I know ethics are not a strongpoint of SO but anyone who helps is as liable as the OP if any damages are pursued.

Comment: Perish the thought--I was just using it as a reproducible example that folks here could relate to.

Comment: _Riiiiight_. I _totally_ believe that.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `paste` function within your read_html argument as follows (or make a seperate variable of it at first):

```
job <- "Bartender"
jobsearch <- read_html(paste("https://www.careerbuilder.com/jobs-data-science?
keywords=",job,"&location=", sep=""))
```